# Can you use xr.open_mfdataset when reading files from S3 via s3fs?

Tags: amazon-s3, netcdf, python-xarray, python-s3fs

I'm trying to read multiple netcdf files at once using `xr.open_mfdataset` from a S3 bucket, using s3fs. Is this possible?

Tried the below, which works for `xr.open_dataset` for a single file, but doesn't work for multiple files:

```
import s3fs
import xarray as xr

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
s3path = 's3://my-bucket/wind_data*'
store = s3fs.S3Map(root=s3path, s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem(), check=False)

data = xr.open_mfdataset(store, combine='by_coords')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exctly what `S3Map` does; the documentation from s3fs isn't specific in this.

However, I was able to create a working implementation of this within a Jupyter environment using `S3FileSystem.glob()` and `S3FileSystem.open()`

Here's a code sample:

```py
import s3fs
import xarray as xr


s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

# This generates a list of strings with filenames
s3path = 's3://your-bucket/your-folder/file_prefix*'
remote_files = s3.glob(s3path)

# Iterate through remote_files to create a fileset
fileset = [s3.open(file) for file in remote_files]

# This works
data = xr.open_mfdataset(fileset, combine='by_coords')
```

Comment: unfortunatly, if you need a preprocess function that uses ds.encoding["source"] it will turn out that "source" is not present in s3fs objects. Do you have an idea about how to overcome this?